# Why copying the entire content of a Hard Disk to a similar Hard Disk of same capacity (5TB) results much extra (140GB+) free space

Tags: linux, hard-drive, backup, ext4

I bought WD Elements 2667 and my old Hard disk is WD my passport 2665.  After copying the entire content of 2nd HDD to 1st HDD, resulted free space of 140GB+ in the new HDD. I checked the size of lost+found on both disks and it was some KBs.

Note that mainly I have Large files (400MB+ to +GBS). I know that Linux in ext4 format, rarely needs defragmation, if any at all. However,as you can see below,  even the size of files differ ~10Mb (Dont know why - cause defragmation maybe?) - note that 3 "missing" files are the log files of rsync but they are some Kbs not MBs!

Dolphin reports:

- Older Disk:      84,178 files, 1,140 sub-folders - 4.2 TiB
  (4,670,978,463,016) - (lost+found = 16K)
- New Backup Disk: 84,181
  files, 1,140 sub-folders - 4.2 TiB (4,670,988,151,764) -(lost+found =
  4K)

Gnome disks report:

- Older Disk:      5.0TB, 295GB free 94.1% filled
- New Backup Disk: 5.0TB, 435GB free 91.3% filled

I used `rsync -navxHAWXS --info=progress2 dir1 dir2` to backup my HDD to the new one.
Due to the huge difference in GBs i used `diff -rq dir1 dir2` to compare all files between disks recursively. It reported only that it cannot access lost+found and my error log file in backup HDD - nothing else! Note that the older HDD has "Reallocated_Event_Count" 564 and 19 pending.

So, I wonder what is the reason of such big difference: a) Defragmation occured at backup HDD disk resulting less space used? (my guess - how to check it?) b) Bad sectors may bind so much space (quite hard to believe)?  c) Even from same company, Hard Disks may differ in (hidden?) size from factory made? (somewhat hard to believe) c) I made any serious error in copying or checking files?

Any guess?

UPDATE
fdisk -l reports for both disks same properties of sectors:
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdj1   2048 9767473151 9767471104  4.5T Linux filesystem

UPDATE SOLUTION
`ls -ksl` on sparse files on both disks showed that they differ much in size!

Comment: One more possibility is smaller sector size (less waste) on the target. Are the partitions of the same size?

Comment: There are no partitions. The entire disk is single-partition

Comment: in both disks, fdisk -l reports:  `Start        End    Sectors  Size Type` -->
  `2048 9767473151 9767471104  4.5T Linux filesystem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you include the flag `-S` in your rsync. From the documentation:

```
       -S, --sparse
              Try to handle sparse files efficiently so they take up less space on the destination.  If combined with --inplace the file
              created might not end up with sparse blocks  with  some  combinations  of  kernel  version  and/or  filesystem  type.   If
              --whole-file is in effect (e.g. for a local copy) then it will always work because rsync truncates the file prior to writ‐
              ing out the updated version.
```

Can it be that you have some sparse files (with big areas of 0 bytes) in there that use less space in the new disk? You can check this by comparing the outputs of `du -sk dir1/*` and `du -sk dir2/*` (and possibly recursing inside some directories that show big discrepancies).

Comment: why `du` not reported such difference?  I checked the part-downloaded torrent files... they report on Dolphin exactly the same size! I dont know.....!!!!

Comment: "The files you moved wont be deleted until they are closed. That means
quiting the torrent client. "du" shows space occupied by files that
actually have a filename. The files you deleted are still there if the
torrent client still has handles on them; they just lack an entry in the
directory and therefore "du" doesn't pick them up, but of course "df"
does since it's not looking at files individually but asks the
filesystem directly."  Here: https://gentoo-user.gentoo.narkive.com/I3qelUhe/sparse-files-and-df ...I dont know... How to check that too?

Comment: `ls -ksl` on sparse files on both disks showed that they differ much in size! So, `du` not report "empty space" difference in files? From here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758905/how-to-compute-the-sparseness-of-files-with-holes

Comment: you mention torrent files that are deleted, but have still open file handles on them, this is of course also a case that would cause the original disk to show less free space, since that space is  not freed yet. To check for these you can run "sudo lsof -n | grep deleted" (might be slow depending on the number of processes, or, if you know the pid of the process keeping the handles, e.g. the torrent process, you can add "-p pid" to the lsof.

Comment: regarding the sparse files, both `ls -ksl` and `du` should show the same number, and that is the actual size occupied on disk by that inode. If these show different in the two disks, it means the actual storage is more or less "sparse" depending probably on many factors how they got created (e.g. in one case the file has actually large blocks of zeroes physically stored on disk, while in the other case there are just pointers saying "there are only zeroes from this to that offset).